# what is an expression that means something that will be there forever?

Tags: nouns

I am looking for a word or two that means "something that will be there forever" as in Mr. Doe passed away. In our family he will be considered a _____________.

Answer (score 1):

For your example you could use **[permanent** | **enduring** | **everlasting] presence**.

Comment: Some*thing* that will be there forever would be *permanent*. Unless smatterer's suggestion is pretty-well perfect, I suggest the Question is far too specific.

Comment: "Eternal" is another word along these lines.